# Consuming and OAuth2 secured API in Grails (Twitter)

Tags: java, grails, groovy, twitter

I am trying to fetch some tweets from twitter using Grails. The twitter API now requires authentication via OAuth2 which I have done before in other frameworks and languages quite easily with some plugins/libraries however I cannot seem to find a working implementation in Grails. Most google searches seem to turn up results relating to using OAuth to authenticate users as the server where as I am trying to have Grails instead act as the client.

[This plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/novadge/twitter-service) looked promising, however the repo for it appears to be broken as the following links to the binaries result in a 404.

https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/twitter/0.2.4/twitter-0.2.4.pom
    https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/twitter/0.2.4/twitter-0.2.4.jar

Does anyone have a working implimentation for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the read me for the twitter plugin is incorrect and the plugin name should be twitter-service in the build.gradle ie:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:twitter-service:0.2.4"
```

For those attempting to do a similar thing you may also have success with the java twitter4j library.